# Admob requires marketplace url for not published app (need MY_AD_UNIT_ID)

Tags: android, admob, ads, adview

I want to place ads on my new application.
I imported the Google Admob SDK but couldn't initiate a new AdView object since it  requires "MY_AD_UNIT_ID".

To receive my MY_AD_UNIT_ID I have to add my app to admob.
Admob requires the maket://-link to my app. But I don't want to release the app without ads. Am I doing this wrong?

**EDIT:
I just noticed that you can delete the market:// and leave the field completely empty. This way you can add your app without any market url.
Since there have been lots of questions about the MY_AD_UNIT_ID I will leave this open.**

Sincerly,
Wolfen

Answer (score 2):

You can easily predict what your app's market URI will be by adding the package name in the basic URI format. For example, if your app has the package `com.example.app`, it's `market://` link will be `market://details?id=com.example.app`.

Comment: thank you but I just noticed that you can delete the market:// and leave the field completely empty. This way you can add your app without any market url.